# Issue with Salesforce Chat - Special characters are not rendering in Web Snap-ins

Tags: magento2

We are using the Salesforce chat feature on our Magento website (Magento 2.4.5), and we are experiencing issues with the rendering of special characters in the chat window. Salesforce has provided a workaround for this issue, which can be found at https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ2UrAAK/special-characters-are-not-rendering-in-web-snap-ins. Can anyone assist me in implementing this workaround on our Magento website? Thank you in advance.